# Cloning audio source without having to download it again

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm creating a piano in the browser using javascript. In order for me to play the same key multiple times simultaneously, instead of just playing the Audio object, I clone it and play the clone, otherwise I'd have to wait for the audio to finish or to restart it, which I don't want.

I've done something like this:

```
var audioSrc = new Audio('path/');
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
    var currentAudioSrc = audioSrc.cloneNode();
    currentAudioSrc.play();
}
```

The problem is, I was checking chrome's inspector, and I noticed that every time I clone the object, the browser download it again

[image]

I checked some people who wanted to achieve similar things, and noticed that most of them have the same problem that I do, they redownload the file. The only example I found that can play the same audio source multiple times simultaneously is SoundJs http://www.createjs.com/SoundJS

I tried checking the source could but couldn't figure out how it was done. Any idea?

---

Comment: Yeah I can see how that would be difficult to track down if you are unfamiliar with the SoundJS architecture.    

WebAudioLoader._sendComplete decodes the loaded file into an AudioBuffer that is then passed as the _result, which is handled in AbstractPlugin._handlePreloadComplete by storing it in the _audioSources hash (WebAudioPlugin extends AbstractPlugin).  This stored AudioBuffer is then passed to each new WebAudioSoundInstance and used for creating audio nodes.    

Its the same idea as the accepted answer, store off the audio buffer and use it to create new audio nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the webAudioAPI you could do something like that :

- Download once the file via XMLHttpRequest.
- Append the response to a buffer
- Create a new bufferSource and play it on each call
- Fallback to your first implementation if webAudioAPI is not supported (IE)

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
if(!window.AudioContext)
  yourFirstImplementation();
else{
var buffer,
ctx = new AudioContext(),
gainNode = ctx.createGain();
gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
var vol = document.querySelector('input');
vol.value = gainNode.gain.value;
vol.addEventListener('change', function(){
    gainNode.gain.value = this.value;
  }, false);

function createBuffer(){
  ctx.decodeAudioData(this.response, function(b) {
    buffer = b;
    }, function(e){console.warn(e)});
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){playSound(buffer)});
  button.className = 'ready';
  }

var file = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3',
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = createBuffer;
xhr.open('GET', file, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.send();

function playSound(buf){
  var source = ctx.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = buf;
  source.connect(gainNode);
  source.onended = function(){if(this.stop)this.stop(); if(this.disconnect)this.disconnect();}
  source.start(0);
  }
}

function yourFirstImplementation(){
  alert('webAudioAPI is not supported by your browser');
  }
```

```css
button{opacity: .2;}
button.ready{opacity: 1};
```

```html
<button>play</button>
<input type="range" max="5" step=".01" title="volume"/>
```

Comment: I can't stop hitting play :D

Comment: is there any way I could control the volume of this audio Buffer?

Comment: @DanielOrtiz Yes sure. You will have to use a gain node. Check update

Answer (score 0):

`cloneNode` have one boolean argument:

```
var dupNode = node.cloneNode(deep);
/*
  node
    The node to be cloned.
  dupNode
    The new node that will be a clone of node
  deep(Optional)
     true if the children of the node should also be cloned, or false to clone only the specified node.
*/
```

Also note from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

> Deep is an optional argument. If omitted, the method acts as if the
>   value of deep was true, defaulting to using deep cloning as the
>   default behavior. To create a shallow clone, deep must be set to
>   false.
>
> This behavior has been changed in the latest spec, and if omitted, the
>   method will act as if the value of deep was false. Though It's still
>   optional, you should always provide the deep argument both for
>   backward and forward compatibility

So, try to use `deep = false` to prevent download resource:

```
var audioSrc = new Audio('path/');
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
    var currentAudioSrc = audioSrc.cloneNode(false);
    currentAudioSrc.play();
}
```

Comment: From my tests it doesn't work for the issue in chrome. Did you manage to avoid the redownload this way?

Answer (score 0):

Load it manually and assign a [Blob URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864573/what-is-a-blob-url-and-why-it-is-used) of the binary data to `src`:

```
<audio id="audioEl" data-src="audio.mp3"></audio>
```

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', audioEl.dataset.src);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = () => {
    audioEl.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
};
xhr.send();
```

This way when you clone it, only the reference to the in-memory binary data is cloned.