# Why does using cloneNode() to create multiple audio files stop me from controlling attributes of the audio source as and how can I override this

Tags: javascript, audio, clonenode

I've been making web games for sometime now and I quickly noticed that once i use the  `.cloneNode(true)`  to play back the same audio file multiple times to avoid re-downloading the file over and over each time I want to play an audio file, I loose control of things such as playback volume and playback rate, does anyone know how I can regain control of those parameters for each copy of the audio file?

> I tried setting the parameters for the audio copies from the original file but no juice

```
In the HTML : 
<audio src = "sight.wav" id="sight"/>
<button onclick="playSound()">Play some audio</audio>

In the Js
var get = new Function("id", "return document.getElementById(id)");

function playSound()
{
  get(sight).volume = 0.30;
  get(sight).playbackRate = 0.40;
  get(sight).cloneNode(true).play();
};
```

Looks like valid code to me but like I said, no juice, the cloneNodes completely ignore the volume and playback settings and just play the normal audio. What should I do?

Comment: Typo: `voluume`

Comment: Why are you using `new Function()` to define an ordinary function?

Comment: It should be `onclick="playSound()"` you're missing the `()`

Comment: oops, didnt notice, thanks!

Comment: I prefer using the `new Function()` syntax to define small functions, it forces me to do that in one line of code

Comment: `const get = id => document.getElementByID(id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) when called on an Element will create a new Element of the same sub-type with the same **attributes** as the original Node.

Here you are not modifying the original's `attributes`, but only some IDL properties that are not reflected and thus not cloned.

```js
const original = document.querySelector("audio");
console.log( "default", [...original.attributes].map( (att) => att.name ) ); // []
original.volume = 0.2;
console.log( "volume set", [...original.attributes].map( (att) => att.name ) ); // []
original.controls = true;
console.log( "controls set", [...original.attributes].map( (att) => att.name ) ); // [ "controls" ]

const clone = original.cloneNode();
console.log( "clone volume", clone.volume ); // 1
console.log( "clone controls", clone.controls ); // true
```

```html
<audio></audio>
```

So you could rewrite your code so that you set the `volume`  and `playBackRate` of your cloned element instead of setting the ones of the original node, but note that if you are really spawning several same audios, you should rather use the Web-Audio API and its [AudioBuffer interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) which offer far greater controls over when these media are played, and which will take far less memory than initializing DOM MediaElements.

Comment: Thanks alot!  Although, I didn't want to use the web audio API cos using it always downloads thw file over and over again, Is there a way I can use the Web audio API to replay the same audio file after it has been download once with the <audio> tag ?

Comment: @Vachila64 sure there is, as I said in my answer, use an AudioBuffer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440830/3702797) for a complete example. (The AudiBufferSourceNodes have a `playbackRate` property).